# Android: Linking a external static C/C++ Library in Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, c, android-studio, native

I've seen many answers to get Native Code working in Android Studio with using Cmake however, not many answers on how to include a pre-compiled C/C++ library into Android. Here are the steps I've taken to try and get a Native Library(trying first with .a) to work.

**1) mylib.c is my C library I want to import into Android Studio**

```
#include "mylib.h"


    int total_foo;

    int foo(float y, float z) { 
    total_foo = y + z;
    return total_foo;

    }
```

**2) mylib.h is the header file for mylib.c**

```
#ifndef _MYLIB_H_
#define _MYLIB_H_

    #define MAX_FOO  20

        struct foo_struct {  
        int x;
        float y;
    };
    typedef struct foo_struct foo_struct;

    extern int total_foo;   

    extern int foo(float y, float z); 

#endif
```

**3) Command for .o file (using NDK with make_standalone_toolchain.py)**

```
$CC -o mylib.o -c mylib.c
```

**4) Command for .a file**

```
ar rcs mylib.a mylib.o
```

**5) Create a Native C++ Project**

Now this is where I am stuck. I've created the Android Studio project with Native C++ support and need to figure out where to put my pre-compiled mylib.a file to be able to make the function call "foo". I seen all different types of places like the jniLibs folder , libs , and  cpp folder. But no examples of what to do after. Like adding the Native Library into the Gradle.

*Putting the code into Android Studio and using Cmake is out since I will only have a Static Library file. *

TLDR: How to add a pre-compiled *.a file into Android Studio.

Comment: The prebuilt library should still be built with the NDK, not with your host computer's GCC or some other toolchain.

Comment: @Michael alright thanks for that tip. I will re-compile the library with NDK once that is completed how would you go about linking it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you have a `mylib.a` somewhere that was built with the NDK, you can link against it in your main shared library like this:

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library(native-main-lib SHARED src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp)

add_library(my_lib STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(my_lib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION path/to/mylib.a)
set_target_properties(my_lib PROPERTIES INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES path/to/mylib/include)

target_link_libraries(native-main-lib my_lib)
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'm in the process of downloading the NDK-build but one last question. Would I need to do anything else to the Gradle/Application or would I be able to call it using static {
        System.loadLibrary("my_lib");
    }

Comment: While support for loading static native libraries from Java has been added in Java SE 8, I'm not sure if that is supported on Android. What you typically do on Android if you have some static library that you want to use is to build a shared library that links against the static library and provides JNI wrappers to call the functions in the static library, and then you load the shared library from Java.