# Including static library archives in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Usually when including native libraries in Android, shared libraries are used and loaded at runtime via `System.load()`.
In my case, I've got a static library (.a archive) compiled for Android which I want to access in Java-Code.

Is it even possible to access static libraries without the approach of linking it in a shared library and then loading the shared library?

I just found following question [linking static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54405275/android-linking-a-external-static-c-c-library-in-android-studio).
The answer is to link the static library into shared library then load the shared library.

Comment: That is correct. A statically linked library cannot be loaded dynamically as-is. You answered your own question :)